# IOS - How to determine carrier name of phone numbers and last call charge for outgoing call in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Can anyone please tell me how to find out the last call charge of an outgoing call and the carrier name of an outgoing call phone number? Is there an API for getting the details of the carrier name and call cost in an iPhone?

Comment: I've never done iPhone programming, so take it with a grain of salt, but I suspect that much of the carrier billing information will not be accessible for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

It is not even about confidentiality or security, although if this info was available, it would be a serious security concern.

The phone does not understand anything related to billing in a wireless/cellular network.  The phone just tries to register on a network, but if the account is inactive or not in good standing, the network will generally reject an attempt to register.

Billing is pretty much handled by the operator's core network (usually the MSC in a circuit switched network, SGSN in a UMTS packet switched network, PDSN in a CDMA/EVDO packet switched network, or the MME in an LTE packet switched network), so it is impossible to get any information on remaining minutes or costs related to a phone call or data transfers.  Any app that provides this information usually does it by approximating it.  Usually it just tracks this info on the phone-level and it may not be official.

The Carrier Name might be available depending on the provider and the technology.  In most technologies, the MCC & MNC of the network will be available, and you can access that carrier name.  This [link](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/carrier-information-mobile-network-code-mnc-and-mobile-country-code-mcc.html) gives you an idea of how to do it for iOS4, but the short version is:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>

// Setup the Network Info and create a CTCarrier object
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init] autorelease];
CTCarrier *carrier = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];

// Get carrier name
NSString *carrierName = [carrier carrierName];
if (carrierName != nil)
  NSLog(@"Carrier: %@", carrierName);

// Get mobile country code
NSString *mcc = [carrier mobileCountryCode];
if (mcc != nil)
  NSLog(@"Mobile Country Code (MCC): %@", mcc);

// Get mobile network code
NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
if (mnc != nil)
  NSLog(@"Mobile Network Code (MNC): %@", mnc);
```

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't.  No there shouldn't be.  No there can't be.  That stuff is confidential.